# Why are my pictures saved in RAW format in manual mode on my Nikon D7200?

Tags: nikon, raw, manual-mode

Does anyone know why my Nikon D7200 saves my pictures as `.nef` when in manual mode?

Image quality is FINE, but I can't figure out how to change it back to saving images as JPEGs. I also want to be able to preview it on the camera's screen.

Answer (score 2):

"Image quality can be set by pressing the X (T) button and rotating the main command dial until the desired setting is displayed in the information display." (page: 79)

"Image quality can also be adjusted using the Image quality option in the photo shooting menu (page: 268)."

I found this in the manual for your camera! You can download it here:

http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/197/D7200.html

Edit: Also, in the manual, there are pictures of the buttons, so it might be clearer what "pressing the X (T)" - means while checking it up inside of it :)

And a tip! When reading the manual in PDF-format, you can press CTRL + F (or cmd + F if you are on a Mac) and search for a part of what you are looking for, like "RAW". And then just press Enter til you find the correct part!